# Convert SQL sub query to LINQ in C#

Tags: sql, linq, subquery

I need to convert these following SQL lines into LINQ query:

```
select  
(  select count(*)
   from vpassSlipApp a
   where a.statusID=0 and a.apprvEIC='xxxxx'
) as pass_slip_app
,
(  select count(*)
   from vPtlosApp a
   where a.Tag=3 and a.approveEIC='xxxxx'
) as ptlos_app
```

I was thinking of doing it like this:

```
var list = ( new {
      pass_slip_app = from r in db.vpassSlipApps
                      where r.statusID == 0
                      where r.apprvEIC == approvingEIC
                      select r.EIC.Count(),
      ptlos_app = from g in db.vPtlosApps
                      where g.Tag == 3
                      where g.approveEIC == approvingEIC
                      select g.controlNo.Count()
                  }
);
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing it like this...var list = (new
                        {
                           pass_slip_app = from r in db.vpassSlipApps
                                where r.statusID == 0
                                where r.apprvEIC == approvingEIC
                                select r.EIC.Count()
                            , ptlos_app = from g in db.vPtlosApps
                                where g.Tag == 3
                                where g.approveEIC == approvingEIC
                                select g.controlNo.Count()
                        })

Comment: @Tatranskymedved: In future, please do not add or edit fluff such as [greetings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) or [edit marks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: thanks for feedback, I'll keep this is mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually need a list? because the sql query returns just 1 record.
This is the query that will return that record as a single object.

```
var x = new { 
            pass_slip_app = vpassSlipApp.Count(a=>a.statusID=0 && a.apprvEIC='xxxxx'), 
            ptlos_app = vPtlosApp.Count(a=>a.Tag=0 && a.approveEIC='xxxxx')
        }
```